# kSOAP XmlPullParserException

Tags: java, android, coldfusion, ksoap2

I'm stumped on a problem trying to consume a ColdFusion SOAP service in Android using kSOAP2.  Here is my java code for invoking a test method I've written in ColdFusion (which only returns a string):

```
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc?WSDL";
private static String URL = "http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "TestMethod";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc?method=TestMethod";

public void GetData() {

    SoapPrimitive resultstring = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    PropertyInfo inputArgs = new PropertyInfo();
    inputArgs.setName("ID");
    inputArgs.setValue(1234);
    inputArgs.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(inputArgs);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope soapenvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    soapenvelope.dotNet = false;
    soapenvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);    

    AndroidHttpTransport httptransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
    //httptransport.debug = true;

    try {
        httptransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapenvelope);
        resultstring = (SoapPrimitive) soapenvelope.getResponse();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(DEBUG, e.getMessage());
    } 
}
```

And here is the ColdFusion test method I've written that only returns a string:

```
    <cfcomponent displayname="test_web_service" namespace="http://www.sub.tv">
            <cffunction name="TestMethod" returnType = "string" access="remote" description="Test Method">
                    <cfargument name="ID" type="numeric">
                    <cfreturn "hello" />
            </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

The error I'm getting when I execute the above Java code is as follows:

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG <html>@2:44 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40ff5440)
```

I suspect the cause of the problem is perhaps the URL I've specified in the SOAP_ACTION but, as far as I know, that's the correct way to invoke a ColdFusion SOAP web service method.  Executing that URL in the browser returns the expected results.  I've tried excluding the method call in the query string of that URL but I still get the same error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time,

Tony

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the display name and the namespace.  I know neither of these are needed when exposing a web service via CFML.  I also suspect that you have an error you're not seeing.  Note that in your error it has:

org.xmlpull.... (position:START_TAG ***<html>***@2:44 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40ff5440)

That html tag suggests to me that your web service is throwing an error.  When CF does this it outputs HTML.  Knowing that, here are a few suggestions.  From a browser:

1) access your service directly in the browser: http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc.  Login to the CF admin and make sure that you see your CFC's documentation.

2) access your WSDL: http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc?wsdl.  You should see your various functions exposed.

3) access your test function: http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc?method=TestMethod&id=123

Actually, since www.sub.tv is public and MyService.cfc is available I tested all of the above for you and it looks like your CFC is good and not throwing errors.

I made a quick test of your CFC:

```
<cfset test = CreateObject("WebService", "http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc?WSDL") />

<cfdump var="#test.TestMethod(123)#" />
```

This outputs "hello", which is what you'd expect if your Web Service is functioning correctly.  This suggests to me that there's an issue in how you're calling it from Android.  I've not done much work with Web Services in Java, so I can only be so helpful here.

However, I noticed that your WSDL defines the test method argument as a Double.  This is normal for CF since a numeric type can hold any type of number.  However, your example code above shows the following:

```
inputArgs.setType(Integer.class);
```

Try changing that to Double.class (or whatever this should be in Java to match the argument type.

That's about all I've got for you. Good luck!

Comment: Hi Doug, huge thanks for your help.  I did indeed try changing the type to Double.class and it unfortunately didn't work - I still received the same error.  As mentioned to Miguel-F I've since changed my parsing engine to SAX to consume an XML response from ColdFusion but will continue to pursue a solution to get kSOAP working.  I'm going to try consume a WCF service with kSOAP next.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is that you are calling a web service via SOAP but the response is not in the expected format (XML).  If you look at the generated output from your web service call http://www.sub.tv/MyService.cfc?method=TestMethod&id=123 you see this:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'>
    <header/>
    <data>
        <string>hello</string>
    </data>
</wddxPacket>
```

This is because *By default, ColdFusion serializes all return types (including simple return types), except XML, into WDDX format...*  [from the CFFunction documentation here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f5c.html)

Try specifying a `returnType` of XML in your ColdFusion function and see if that works. You may still need to tweak the output to get what `kSOAP` is expecting. I don't know the XML format it wants but this should get you started.

Change your `CFFunction` to something like this:

```
<cffunction name="TestMethod" returnType="xml" access="remote" description="Test Method">
    <cfargument name="ID" type="numeric">
    <cfset var xml = "">
    <cfxml variable="xml">
        <test>hello</test>
    </cfxml>
    <cfreturn xml>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Hi Miguel-F, many thanks for the response.  Unfortunately kSOAP2 still threw an error when returning XML.  To avoid delays in my project I've changed the parsing engine I'm using from kSOAP to SAX - which parses XML perfectly fine.  I would still like to use kSOAP in the future so I'll continue to pursue a solution for it - if I do I'll return to post the solution (with a smug smile on my face!)